# ModuleNotFoundError No module named apt_pkg

Tags: python, linux, apt

I am trying to add a repo using command

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa
```

Following is complete error -

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module> from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 27, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module> from apport.report import Report
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module> from apport.packaging_impl 
import impl as packaging 
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module> from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 27, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

getting above error.

I have install python2 , Python3.5 & Python3.6 installed on Xubuntu 16.04.
Does it causing any issue???

Comment: Your question might be better suited for https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: For starters though: do you have a file `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`?

Comment: Thanks. Found the problem. My Python3 was linked to python3.6 but when changed to 3.5.2 started working. Maybe Python 3.6 is not fully supported yet

Comment: That's weird, because it never should have been linked that way in the first place.

Comment: And yes, Python 3.6 is likely not supported *at the system level*, since the system is supposed to be stable, thus sticking to the major.minor versions it started off with. If you want to install and use Python 3.6 (or 3.7 in a month's time or so), install it in `/usr/local`.

Answer (score 12):

This is likely because you switched python versions in a weird way. Do you have `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.so` ? This can be missing if you removed a version of python.

The answer that worked for me was this from [askubuntu forums](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069087/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-apt-pkg-error?noredirect=1&lq=1):

```
ln -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.so
```

Answer (score 10):

If you look at `/usr/bin/add-apt-repository` it says

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

at the top. If you updated with a newer python (e.g. dist had 3.5 but you installed 3.7) your `/usr/bin/python3` points to a python that does not have `apt_pkg`.

You can temporarily edit `/usr/bin/add-apt-repository` to point to

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
```

(insert your distro python version)

Comment: What does it mean if I don't have a `/usr/bin/add-apt-repository`?

Comment: @YourCodeMadeMeSuicidal you need to install software-properties-common

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem, when doing apt-get upgrade... The problem is that apt-get was trying to use python2.7, but the symlink was pointing to python3.4:

```
debian:/usr/bin# cat /etc/debian_version
8.10
debian:/usr/bin# ll /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Feb 26 17:02 /usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python3.4
```

Fixed it by creating a new symlink

```
debian:/usr/bin# rm /usr/bin/python
debian:/usr/bin# ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: I was able to fix a similar problem with `apt-add-repository`, only this time I had to relink my `python3` to point to `python3.5` instead of 3.6. Some concept though.

Answer (score -3):

Install python-dev module for specific version of python:

```
sudo apt install python3.6-dev
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't change anything :/